# SharePoint 2010 error 0x81020026, “The page you selected contains a list that does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.”

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I get this nasty exception in one of my SharePoint servers (version 2010).

> SharePoint error 0x81020026, "The page
>   you selected contains a list that does
>   not exist. It may have been deleted by
>   another user."

The SharePoint server has been setup by using it's netbios name - "customer-intranet" and the error only occurs when we are trying to upload upload a document or create a new list item using it's FQDN or IP (intranet.customer.com, 192,168.11.11). And everything works fine when we access the server with it's netbios name so the lists are there and they do work just fine!

Any advices?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be helpful:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010general/thread/150aca88-c32c-4dbf-9f79-638ae438d1a0

Comment: Thanks, I've already looked at that one but came to their solution was to go through the hostname anyway. *arghs* :/